# Django order_by() is not working along with distinct()

Tags: django, django-models, sql-order-by, django-filters, django-aggregation

How can i use **order_by()** in combination with **distinct()** ?

I am having multiple same **run_id** with different **end_time** and trying to filter distinct run_id and order by end_time

```
data = list(table_name.objects.filter(experience=experience)\
.values('run_id', 'end_time').distinct('run_id').order_by('-end_time'))
```

Following is the error :-

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

However, the `following ORM works fine without order_by` but I want the latest end_time

```
data = list(table_name.objects.filter(experience=experience).values('run_id', 'end_time').distinct('run_id'))
```

Comment: Also see the *notes* in the [documentation for `distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is database?

Try:

```
data = list(table_name.objects.filter(experience=experience)\
.values('run_id', 'end_time').distinct('run_id').order_by('run_id', '-end_time'))[::1]
```

Comment: not working....i mean its not sorted by latest end_time

Comment: occur any error?   
data = list(table_name.objects.filter(experience=experience)\
.values('run_id', 'end_time').distinct('run_id').order_by('run_id', '-end_time'))[::1]

Comment: There is no error, got distinct values of run_id and end_time, but sorted as per the latest end_time

Comment: This worked :) `data = list(table_name.objects.filter(experience=experience).values('run_id', 'end_time').distinct('end_time').order_by('end_time', 'run_id'))[::-1]
`

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct), `distinct(*fields)` only works on PostrgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

The column in distinct() must also be in order_by()

```
data = list(table_name.objects.filter(experience=experience)\
.values('run_id', 'end_time').distinct('run_id').order_by('run_id', '-end_time'))
```

Comment: tried this, but this is not sorted by latest end_time, its kind of mixed

Comment: @Mahesh yes of course, because they are ordered by `run_id` first (which is necessary since you want to make a distinct on it).

Comment: Thanks. this worked `data = list(table_name.objects.filter(experience=experience).values('run_id', 'end_time').distinct('end_time').order_by('end_time', 'run_id'))[::-1]
`